# Increase text size of the plot using ggcuminc

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a plot comparing two groups using ggcuminc. This is a competing risk model with death and outcome as competing risks. But the text size is too small. I figured out how to increase the size of risk table, but not other text components. Any thoughts?

```
#plot the event, according to med status

fit <- fit %>%
  mutate(oac = ifelse(oac == 1, "warfarin", "Non-Warfarin"))
    
cuminc(Surv(lof, status) ~ oac, data = fit)

ggcuminc(theme=theme_ggsurvfit_default(), size = 2) +
  labs(
    y = "cumulative incidence, %",
    x = "Follow up time (Month)"
  ) +

  add_confidence_interval() +

  add_risktable(
    times = NULL,
    risktable_stats = c("n.risk"),
    risktable_group = c("auto", "strata", "risktable_stats")<
    risktable_height = NULL,
    combine_groups = FALSE,
    size = 6) +

  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::percent)  +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,3,6,12,24))

dev.off()
```

[image: competing risk plot]

Comment: Can't see anything specific regarding the table labels in the `add_risktable` documentation, but you could try changing the `risktable_height =` value. risktable_height =` accepts values from 0 to 1, which indicates the proportion of the final plot the risk table will occupy.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font size of the other text components via `theme()` as you would in a ggplot2. You can also customise the font size of the risk table to your liking.

I'm using the 'trial' dataset provided in the tidycmprsk package to demonstrate:

```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(tidycmprsk)
   library(ggsurvfit)

   cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, trial) %>%
     ggcuminc(outcome = "death from cancer") +
     add_confidence_interval() +
     add_risktable(size = 4,
                   theme = theme_risktable_default(axis.text.y.size = 12,
                                                   plot.title.size = 12)) +
     theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
           axis.text = element_text(size = 15),
           legend.text = element_text(size = 15))
```

[image]